# Activating authguard for current route on log out (Angular)

Tags: angular

My angular app has two routes with a route guard

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: MenuComponent},
  {path: 'tableChartGFS', canActivate:[AuthGuard] ,component: TableDataChartGfsComponent},
  {path: 'tableAccount', canActivate:[AuthGuard] ,component: TableDataAccountComponent},
  {path: 'auth', component: AuthComponent}
];
```

The route guard checks if a user is currently logged in or not (by checking if the user BehaviorSubject is currently null or set to a user instance)

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}
  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ):
    | boolean
    | UrlTree
    | Promise<boolean | UrlTree>
    | Observable<boolean | UrlTree> {
    return this.authService.user.pipe(
      map((user) => {
        const isAuth = !!user;

        if (isAuth) {
          return true;
        }

        return this.router.createUrlTree(['/auth']);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

When I log in and go to the /tableAccount route and then click "log out" (which sets the user BehaviorSubject to null) I want to be redirected to the main MenuComponent since I am not allowed to be on this route anymore. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually have a logout function to handle the logout logic and I pass the dependencies (router, toaster, services, etc...) Something like this

`function logout(router: Router, userSrv: userService) {
    router.navigateByUrl('auth');
    userSrv.user.next(undefined);
}`